# Modern Maven Pom Templates

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, maven-archetype, giter8

Every time I make a new *proper* project using Maven hosted on Github I have to go look at either one of my own old projects and copy the pom file or I go find a project that I think does a good job and copy there POM file. Then I have to go search and replace things like project name... etc.

Now Maven has a solution to this through archetypes but I have yet to see one that is modern enough such that it:

- Uses the release plugin and deploys to SonaType Central Maven reop.
- Connects to Github (meaning the scm connections and release plugin work do the right thing)
- Makes all *three* jar artifacts (sources, javadoc, and regular jar)

I have contemplated make some [giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8) templates but was hoping somebody already did something like this (most of the g8 templates are for `sbt`).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "connects to Github".

Comment: I mean the release plugin works with git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out its incredible easy to create your own maven archetype.

1. Just make a generic project with stuff you like to use
2. In the project directory run `mvn archetype:create-from-project`
3. Generally Maven guesses the right things to make variable but if not you just edit the Velocity templates.
4. Install your archetype locally with `mvn install`
5. To use your new archetype: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.mygroup -DarchetypeArtifactId=my-archetype`

Now the only caveat is that there is not very good doc on the web that I could find on the archetype system. Like its unclear what variables you have available to you for Velocity (although most of them are obvious).

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`com.jcabi:parent:pom`](http://parent.jcabi.com/index.html) which does exactly what you need and many more. It deploys to Sonatype, defines common dependencies with versions, pre-configures most popular plugins, and defines a few useful profiles.

This article explains more: [Don't Repeat Yourself in Maven POMs; Use Jcabi-Parent](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/02/05/jcabi-parent-maven-pom.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [parent pom](http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom) released by Sonatype. It's intended to be used as a parent pom for projects that deploy to `oss.sonatype.org` (which may or may not be promoted to Maven Central).

When the sonatype-oss-release profile is enabled, it will ensure that sources and javadocs are built. It also includes an example of the `<scm>` pom element.

Comment: I know about that but it like the multiple inheritance problem. I would rather not inherit sonatype super pom.

Comment: I know what you mean. It may still be useful as an example. That is, it shows how to get source and javadocs attached.